# Simplifying logarithmic integral $Li(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering if someone could suggest me a hint on how to obtain the following expression
$$
Li(x) = \int_{0}^x \frac{1}{\log y} dy = \int_{1}^x (1 - \frac{1}{ y}) \frac{1}{ \log y} dy
+ \log \log x + \gamma,
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant. 
It is in the book I am reading without explanation, and I couldn't quite get it to work when I tried. Thank you very much!

Comment: Which book was that?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You may just observe that
$$
(\log | \log y|)'=\frac{ 1/y}{\log y}=\frac1{y\log y}
$$ using
$$
(\log |u|)' = \frac{u'}{u}.
$$ Then, 
$$
\begin{align}
Li(x) &= \int_{a_0}^x \frac{1}{\log y} dy \qquad \qquad (a_0>e)\\\\
&=\int_{a_0}^x (1 - \frac{1}{ y}) \frac{1}{ \log y} dy+\int_{a_0}^x \frac{1}{ y} \frac{1}{ \log y} dy\\\\
&=\int_{a_0}^x (1 - \frac{1}{ y}) \frac{1}{ \log y} dy
+ \log \log x + C
\end{align}
$$ and take $C=-\log \log a_0+\gamma$.

Comment: Is it a typo in the book then that the integral starts at $y=0$ instead of at $y = a_0 > e$?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Yes, there is probably a typo, otherwise what is written is nonsense. Thanks.

Comment: Also how can we take $C = - \log \log a_0 + \gamma$ when the integral is a definite integral? I thought we don't have a choice for $C$ here?

Comment: @JohnnyT. This is possible just because $a_0$ was not beforehand chosen.

Answer (score 0):

If the equality between integrals would be true, then by splitting your second integral, one would have
$$
\int_0^x\frac{1}{y\log y}\,dy=\log\log x+\gamma.
$$
However, the integral
$$
\int_0^x\frac{1}{y\log y}\,dy
$$
diverges (the singularity at zero is too strong).